# How to use external libraries?

Tags: python, python-import

```
pip install pillow
```

```
>>> Requirement already satisfied: pillow in c:\users\miguel\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (8.3.1)
```

```
import pillow
```

```
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Miguel\PycharmProjects\Testing\main\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pillow
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pillow'
```

for some reason I can't use any downloaded libraries on Pycharm without getting this error. Tried searching it up but with no answers. I think it must be some sort of pathing error. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possible answers :
While the name of the package is pillow, it is a replacement for PIL and uses the PIL for the name of the base module

the usual way to use pillow is

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("filename")
```

2. Go to your IDE and make sure existing interpreter is set to python interpreter and not anaconda

- Open up your Project Interpreter (⌘ + , on Mac).
- At the bottom of this page you'll see the + symbol to the left of the anaconda logo. This will create a pop-up that allows you to search for available packages.
- In this new window, search for 'Pillow'.
- Click and Install Package.

Comment: i've tried importing PIL aswell, with no success, Yes, i'm using python 3.9 as an interpreter,
and the download command in the anaconda website also says requirements already satisfied

Comment: Pycharm has its own Python installation, does it not?